# Welch for 2d (or nd) in python

Tags: numpy, scipy, fft

I am looking for an implementation of [Welch periodogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welch%27s_method), similar to [scipy.signal.welch](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.welch.html) that handles nd array.

Things I tried :

- [Numpy allows for nd fft](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fft.fftn.html) using `fftn` but does not provide Welch algorithm.
- I cannot compute Welch along all axes because `scipy.signal.welch` returns a periodogram, not the raw fourier transform

I guess I could try to reproduce `scipy.signal.welch` using numpy functions to implement nd-welch, but I'd prefer any available method.

Comment: It's not immediately obvious from your links what extending this to 2d involves.  Is it just doing the 1d separately on each row (or column)?  You can read the `signal` docs just as well as we can.  https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/signal.html#spectral-analysis.  This `welch` is just as special case of the `csd` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found what I wanted [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/63999/python-implementation-of-multidimensional-power-spectral-density-with-welch-meth), which really just extents the 1-d welch to n-d, although with no reference